# Drupal 8 Reply To contact module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I use the contact module in a Drupal 8 website and I would like to remove or change the "reply to" field. I tried to use the hook mail alter but it always add the user's mail to the reply-to field... Here is the beginning of the hook mail alter :

```
 function contact_didier_contact_site_formatmail(&$message) {

  unset($message['reply-to']);
  unset($message['headers']['Reply-To']);

  $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes';
  $message['reply-to'] = $message['headers']['From'] = $message['headers']['Sender'] =
  $message['headers']['Return-Path'] = $message['headers']['Errors-To'] = $message['headers']['Reply-To'] = $message['params']['contact_message']->get('field_email')
    ->getValue()[0]['value'];
```

And even with that code, I get two adresses in the "reply to" field... (The one from the connected user, and the other that I want ($message['params'['contact_message']->get('field_email')->getValue()[0]['value'])

I don't know if I'm clear enough in my description, if you need more informations please tell me !

Thanks a lot,
Ghislain.

Comment: Ghislain Why are you using `reply-to` instead of `Reply-To` on line 7 of your code ? Have you tried different syntaxes ?

Comment: Hi @NazimLachter thanks I've found the answer by my own not so long after my post and that was that... It will teach me to copy/paste some random code on stack overflow...